# Correct type specialization

Tags: typescript, overloading, typescript-generics

I wrote an overloaded function like in this [CR question](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/240452/14363) and it works, except for the typing.

There are specialized helper methods like

```
function booleanAgg(
    value: boolean,
    setter: Dispatch<SetStateAction<boolean>>,
    makeSetter: (value: boolean) => ((event?: any) => void)) {
    ...
}
```

used in the main method

```
export function useStateEx<S extends boolean|string|number>(initialState: S) : unknown {
    ...
    if (typeof value === 'boolean') {
        // @ts-ignore
        return [value, setter, booleanAgg(value, setter, makeSetter)]
    ...
}
```

Obviously typescript sees that `value` is boolean and it reports `(S & false) | (S & true)`, which is AFAIK exactly `S & boolean`. With more complex types, this doesn't seem to work as the error message says:

```
Argument of type 'Dispatch<SetStateAction<S>>' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Dispatch<SetStateAction<boolean>>'.
  Type 'SetStateAction<boolean>' is not assignable to type 'SetStateAction<S>'.
    Type 'false' is not assignable to type 'SetStateAction<S>'.ts(2345)
```

With `@ts-ignore`, it works well, but how can I get the types right?

#### A minimal reproducible example

```
import { useState } from 'react';

function booleanAgg(
    value: boolean,
    setter: (value: boolean) => void,
    makeSetter: (value: boolean) => ((event?: any) => void)) {
    throw new Error('irrelevant');
}

export function useStateEx<S extends boolean|string|number>(initialState: S) : unknown {
    const [value, setter]: [S, (v: S) => void] = useState(initialState);
    function makeSetter(value: S) : ((value: boolean) => ((event?: any) => void)) {
        throw new Error('irrelevant');
    }
    if (typeof value === 'boolean') {
        // @ts-ignore
        return [value, setter, booleanAgg(value, setter, makeSetter)];
    } else {
        throw new Error('irrelevant');
    }
}
```

#### New error message

After adapting the example as suggested in the comments, the erro message has changed:

```
Argument of type '(v: S) => void' is not assignable to parameter of type '(value: boolean) => void'.
  Types of parameters 'v' and 'value' are incompatible.
    Type 'boolean' is not assignable to type 'S'.
      'boolean' is assignable to the constraint of type 'S', but 'S' could be instantiated with a different subtype of constraint 'string | number | boolean'.ts(2345)
```

Comment: This isn't a [mcve] unless you follow a link, but ideally it should be self-contained in this question.  In any case, do you have a reason why `useStateEx()` needs to be generic?  If you replace `S` with just `string | boolean | number`, does that work for you?

Comment: @jcalz Added full compilable code. It looks like replacing `S` with `string | boolean | number` *avoids* the problem. But that's just because of the overloads defined separately and it's probably no good idea as I may later want to use things like `useStateEx('one' as 'one'|'two'|'three');`. I guess, I'll have to make the specialized helpers generic, too, because of this?

Comment: I think your use case is pushing the TS engine too hard. Quite hard to get this one right. I myself would just mute the errors and annotate the input output types explicitly.

Comment: TS is supposed to help you. Don't pick a fight with it for no good reason. Why don't you instead focus on getting the proper return type? I think that's bigger gain.

Comment: If this question depends on the definition of `useState` from react then you should consider adding a react tag to the question.  Otherwise you should consider modifying the example to be self-contained (e.g., make a toy overloaded function that has the issue you're trying to deal with).  I'm not a react expert so I'm not sure what to say here.

Comment: Without knowing more about react I'd say this is likely to be an instance of [microsoft/Typecript#13995](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/13995), which is why I originally suggested not to have the function be generic unless there's something important it buys you.  Generic functions where the type parameter appears in only one place in the call signature are often not very useful, and microsoft/TypeScript#13995 limits the usefulness of generic type parameters inside function implementations.  Does that explain things? If so, I'll write up an answer.

Comment: @jcalz As suggested, I made it rather react-independend (I kept `useState`, but added the type). Thank you for all your comments. I guess, I'll need the generics, when I'll generalize the code. I believe, you're wrong with #13995 being the culprit, but that's just a feeling. `+++` Now, I get a different error message, see the bottom of the question. I guess, the problem is that `S & boolean` is not `boolean`, but could be narrower (e.g., with `s = false`....

Comment: If you replace the generic `S` with concrete `boolean`, it would work.  If you replace it with `number`, it would work.  If you replace it with `string`, it would work.  But you can't tell the compiler to perform such analysis without performing those different things yourself as separate code.  For generic types, this is what #13995 is about, as well as possible solutions to this like [microsoft/TypeScript#27808](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/27808).  Can you explain why you feel it's not relevant?

Comment: There is a wrinkle where `boolean` is equivalent to the union `true | false`, but if you switch to `string` or `number` (not union types) instead you'll likely have the same problem.

Comment: @jcalz Thank you for you comments and especially links. It's a bit too complicated for me at the moment. I realized, I'll need generics, at least in the declarations, e.g., when dealing with enums. So I added them pretty everywhere and this partly solved my problem.

Comment: @jcalz I sort of solved it by adding more generics. It may or mayn't be better than it was; we'll see.

Answer (score 0):

I could partly solve the problem by adding more generics. To make the code compile without react, replace the import by the following declarations:

```
function useState<S>(initialState: S | (() => S)): [S, Dispatch<SetStateAction<S>>];
type Dispatch<A> = (value: A) => void;
type SetStateAction<S> = S | ((prevState: S) => S);
```

The full code:

```
import { useState, Dispatch, SetStateAction } from 'react';

interface BaseAgg<S extends boolean|string|number> {
    value: S
    setter: (value: S) => void
}

interface BooleanAgg extends BaseAgg<boolean> {
    falseHandler: (event?: any) => void,
    trueHandler: (event?: any) => void,
    toggleHandler: (event?: any) => void,
}

interface NormalAgg<S extends string|number> extends BaseAgg<S> {
    makeSetter: (value: S) => ((event?: any) => void)
    changeHandler: (e: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement|HTMLTextAreaElement>) => void
}

function booleanAgg(value: boolean, setter: (value: boolean) => void, makeSetter: (value: boolean) => ((event?: any) => void)) : BooleanAgg {
    return {
        value,
        setter,
        falseHandler: makeSetter(false),
        trueHandler: makeSetter(true),
        toggleHandler: makeSetter(!value),
    };
}

function stringAgg<S extends string>(value: S, setter: (value: S) => void, makeSetter: (value: S) => ((event?: any) => void)) : NormalAgg<S> {
    return {
        value,
        setter,
        makeSetter,
        changeHandler: (e: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement|HTMLTextAreaElement>) => {
            e.stopPropagation();
            setter(e.currentTarget.value as S);
        }
    };
}

function numberAgg<S extends number>(value: S, setter: (value: S) => void, makeSetter: (value: S) => ((event?: any) => void)) : NormalAgg<S> {
    return {
        value,
        setter,
        makeSetter,
        changeHandler: (e: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement|HTMLTextAreaElement>) => {
            e.stopPropagation();
            setter(+e.currentTarget.value as S);
        }
    };
}

/**
 * Works like useState and adds a third element containing boolean-specific handlers directly useable in buttons and checkboxes.
 */
export function useStateEx<S extends boolean>(initialState: S) : [S, Dispatch<SetStateAction<S>>, BooleanAgg];

/**
 * Works like useState and adds a third element containing string-specific handlers directly useable in text fields.
 */
export function useStateEx<S extends string>(initialState: S) : [S, Dispatch<SetStateAction<S>>, NormalAgg<S>];

/**
 * Works like useState and adds a third element containing number-specific handlers directly useable in text fields.
 */
export function useStateEx<S extends number>(initialState: S) : [S, Dispatch<SetStateAction<S>>, NormalAgg<S>];

/**
 * Prohibits use with any type not handled in the above overloads.
 */
export function useStateEx(initialState: any) : never;

export function useStateEx<S extends boolean|string|number>(initialState: S) : unknown {
    const [value, setter] = useState(initialState);
    function makeSetter(value: S) {
        return function(e: any) {
            if (typeof e?.stopPropagation === 'function') e.stopPropagation();
            setter(value);
        };
    }
    switch (typeof value) {
    case 'boolean': return [value, setter, booleanAgg(value, setter as any, makeSetter as any)];
    case 'string': return [value, setter, stringAgg(value, setter, makeSetter)];
    case 'number': return [value, setter, numberAgg(value, setter, makeSetter)];
    }
}
```

I didn't add generics for the boolean case as I don't want to deal with `S extends boolean` - a type like `false` with its single value can't be used as state. So the generic argument I'd like to use is in pseudocode `S=boolean || S extends number|string`, which AFAIK can't be expressed.